# Symfony 2 how to access object(stdClass)

Tags: symfony, object, stdclass

I got a variable involving several objects in symfony2 two with the method

```
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($article);
```

I've got

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#267 (19) { ["__CLASS__"]=> string(30) "obbex\AdsBundle\Entity\AdsList" ["id"]=> int(33) ["username"]=> string(7) "aviator" ["email"]=> string(17) "aviator@gmail.com" ["telephone"]=> string(4) "5161" 
["displayPhone"]=> string(3) "non" ["title"]=> string(14) "aviator jacket" ["description"]=> string(14) "aviator jacket" ["country"]=> string(6) "France" 
["region"]=> string(13) "Ile de France" ["department"]=> string(5) "Paris" ["address"]=> string(15) "15, rue Dantzig" ["city"]=> string(5) "Paris" ["zipCode"]=> 
string(5) "75015" ["statusPro"]=> string(3) "oui" ["creationtime"]=> string(8) "DateTime" ["updatetime"]=> string(8) "DateTime" ["publication"]=> bool(true) ["photos"]=> string(8) "Array(1)" } }
```

with

```
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($article[0]);
```

I've got access to the first array slot [0]

```
object(stdClass)#267 (19) { ["__CLASS__"]=> string(30) "obbex\AdsBundle\Entity\AdsList" ["id"]=> int(33) ["username"]=> string(7) "aviator" ["email"]=> string(17) 
"aviator@gmail.com" ["telephone"]=> string(4) "5161" ["displayPhone"]=> string(3) "non" ["title"]=> string(14) "aviator jacket" ["description"]=> string(14) "aviator jacket" ["country"]=> string(6) "France" ["region"]=> string(13) "Ile de France" 
["department"]=> string(5) "Paris" ["address"]=> string(15) "15, rue Dantzig" ["city"]=> string(5) "Paris" ["zipCode"]=> string(5) "75015" ["statusPro"]=> string(3) "oui" ["creationtime"]=> object(stdClass)#365 (3) { ["__CLASS__"]=> string(8) "DateTime" ["date"]=> string(25) "2014-06-06T21:54:00+02:00" ["timezone"]=> string(12) "Europe/Paris" }
 ["updatetime"]=> object(stdClass)#366 (3) { ["__CLASS__"]=> string(8) "DateTime" ["date"]=> string(25) "-001-11-30T00:00:00+00:09" ["timezone"]=> string(12) "Europe/Paris" } ["publication"]=> bool(true) ["photos"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(29) "obbex\AdsBundle\Entity\Photos" } }
```

how to access the first object(stdClass) 'obbex\AdsBundle\Entity\AdsList'
I've tried

```
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($article[0]->{'obbex\AdsBundle\Entity\AdsList'});
```

and

```
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($article[0]->'obbex\AdsBundle\Entity\AdsList');
```

with no success.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies in how you (de-)serialize your object. I assume you want an `obbex\AdsBundle\Entity\AdsList`-object instead of a `stdClass`-object.

What you could do is, check for `__CLASS__` and then create a new object from that passing the `stdClass`-object in the constructor to pass the data:

```
$rawData = (array) $article[0]; // Convert stdClass to array for easier handling
$className = $rawData['__CLASS__'];
// TODO Maybe check, that class name is valid
$object = new $className($rawData);
```

Your class then just needs to populate its properties from the array in the constructor:

```
namespace obbex\AdsBundle\Entity;

class AdsList
{
    protected $username;
    protected $email;
    ...

    public function __construct(array $data = array())
    {
        if (empty($data)) {
            return;
        }

        // TODO Check only valid properties/values are used
         $this->username = $data['username'];
         ...
         // OR
         foreach ($data as $name => $value) {
             $this->{$name} = $value;
         }
    }
}
```

You could save yourself some trouble by making sure you retrieve the actual object instead of `stdClass`, e.g. by making sure `serialize()` and `deserialize(string $serialized)` are implemented/used.